# telegram InlineKeyboardButton dos not show

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

i do not now way .i have copy this code exactly from  [Telegram.Bot.Examples.Echo](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot.examples/blob/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Echo/Program.cs)
but it just send message without eny inline button
please help me

```
var inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
                      {
                          new [] 
                          {
                              InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1.1"),
                              InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1.2","test"),
                          }
                      });

                await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    message.Chat.Id,
                    "Choose",
                    replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard);
```

my current version :13.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is conflict between api and targeted framework

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with inlineKeyboard - bot didn't received the CallbackData. Maby there is an another solution but just creating a new bot worked for me.